# Is customizing DispatcherServlet in Spring MVC a common practice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. But I had certain experience in working with Struts 1.x. I would like to know if it is a common practice to customize **DispatcherServlet** while working with Spring MVC, like people sometimes customize **ActionServlet** or **RequestProcessor** in Struts 1.x?

Or let's extend the question a little bit. Where are the entry points for a veteran Spring MVC programmer to customize the MVC framework?

Thank you.

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by customize - do you mean specialize (as I answered) or configure (as adatapost answered)?

Comment: Actually I mean both, since I need all the information about extending it.
Moreover, I agree with you point. Extending DispatcherServlet and be replaced by using Filter or Controller. However, this way, Spring MVC is not able to offer a standard plig-in interface for plug-in developers. In struts, some plug-ins are done by extending "RequestProcessor".

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the Struts plug-in architecture but I would say the Spring MVC API is pretty bare-bones.  It's a little misnamed imho, as it's only really the controller part of the MVC pattern leaving you to define your views and model as necessary (typically as JSPs and POJOs).

Comment: Yeah, but it's serving almost(if not all) all the requirement quite alright. It's a nice framework. I like it pretty much.

Comment: Oh yeah, Spring MVC is great - it's integrated nicely with Spring and does just enough to get the request to you, after which you can do just what you like with it.  It's by far my preferred way of building web-apps, with web-standards XHTML/CSS and JQuery on the front end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely it is a good practice. [Spring Framework - Web MVC framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html)

> SUMMARY: You can customize Spring's
>   DispatcherServlet by adding context
>   parameters .... especially handy when
>   you have a lot of common functionality
>   in one controller.

Answer (score 5):

`DispatcherServlet`, like most of the Spring API, is very much designed for extension. Indeed, if you find a part of it that's not ammenable to subclassing, file an issue on their JIRA and they'll likely fix it for you (I've done that on a number of occasions).

Having said that, the vast majority of functionality can be achieved via configuration of `DispatcherServlet` rather than extension of it.

Comment: You are right. I cannot even name a single thing that cannot be achieved by it's current implementation. Thank you for your advise. I will file a issue if I find the necessity.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion where I am thinking that extending the dispatcher servlet would be 'a' solution.

1. separate validation, conversion from controller (for several good reasons)
2. make the controller just a delegator to service layer.
3. build/populate the domain/request object fully 'before' it reaches the controller.

Comment: If you think it's a good way, go ahead and implement it. Even though I asked this question in the first place, I haven't found a case in which I must extend DispatcherServlet.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want specialize [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html)?

Any request pre-processing can/should be achieved with a [javax.servlet.Filter](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and the rest is down to the implementation of [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html).

Alternatively see *adatapost*'s answer, which refers to configuration of the [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) via the web.xml file.

Comment: I ask this question so that I can understand this framework better, and to see what this way can serve. :)

Comment: Why would you want to specialize anything ? Because you may have a need that someone else has not yet. So I can't understand how such answers can have an upvote anyway. If a class has "protected" methods, which DispatcherServlet has, it definitely means the developer believes that there may occur a need to override it. Grails developers have already overriden DispatcherServlet and for them Filters were not enough to customize some functionality.

Comment: There's always that possibility that you can specialize, but the question asked whether it was common, which imho, it isn't and there are normally better ways to achieve what you need, although granted, this may not always be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I, for one, have never found a reason to extend DispatcherServlet.